# Integration in Maple 16

Tags: integration, math-software, maple

I need to solve this integral in Maple 16, I've tried various functions such as `evalf`, `solve`, `simplify`, `numeric`, etc. In Wolfram Alpha Pro can solve quickly, but the maple does not solve! Can someone help me?

```
int((e^(-(0.25 (y-2.)^2)/y) ((0.0805163*y+0.161033)*erf(0.942809+0.288675 *sqrt(y)-0.57735/sqrt(y))+0.0805163 y+0.161033))/y^(3/2),y=0..infinity)
```

I thank you!

Comment: In Maple you might need multiplication signs (thus: `*`) before terms like `erf` and `sqrt`. In other words, you can't write things like `y = a sin(x)`; instead, write `y = a*sin(x)`.

Comment: Thank you friend, but unfortunately this is not the problem! I copied this formula and for some reason did not come the multiplication signs, but I still have problems with maple to solve this integral!

Comment: Try replacing your e^   by exp().  When then using evalf, I get something

Comment: Thank you, really worked! Funny, because in my role with the parameters used exp () when replacing the values Maple own switched to e ^ and I did not realize! Thanks, it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Théophile and @Jean-Sébastien have correctly pointed out the syntax issues with your code.

Maple 18 is facing no difficulty to evaluate this integral directly. You just need to use `evalf` to get the answer.

```
int((exp(-(0.25*(y-2.)^2)/y)*((0.0805163*y+0.161033)*erf(0.942809+0.288675*sqrt(y)-0.57735/sqrt(y))+0.0805163* y+0.161033))/y^(3/2),y=0..infinity);

evalf(%);
               `1`
```

Another way is to plot it and try to make some sense out it.

```
f:=x->evalf(Int((exp(-(0.25*(y-2.)^2)/y)*((0.0805163*y+0.161033)*erf(0.942809+0.288675*sqrt(y)-0.57735/sqrt(y))+0.0805163* y+0.161033))/y^(3/2), y=x..infinity,method = _d01amc)):

plot(f,0..100,color=red,thickness=4,axes=boxed);
```

[image]